# Accidentally set gas price too low?

Tags: transactions, gas, gas-price, fees

I’m fairly new to Crypto and have just made a recent transaction but I accidentally set my gas price and transaction fee too low therefore the amount needed to be mined is incredibly high, here is the transaction link https://bscscan.com/tx/0xa0e128a866bb474e3ab2e7659ef4bcb9b1a688c73ae9110aff34b8e159dbb1e3
Is there anyway I can speed this up? Or even cancel it?

Comment: Hi there. Which wallet did you use for submitting the transaction?

Comment: I used my meta mask wallet.

Answer (score 1):

As you've used Metamask, you should be able to either cancel the transaction or speed it up using the UI.

In the Activity tab you should see your pending transaction. Below it there should be a "Speed Up" button and a "Cancel" button:

[image]

See [this](https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015489251-How-to-Speed-Up-or-Cancel-a-Pending-Transaction) post for more details.